# How do I set the Foreground property of a TextBlock by TextBlock text value?

Tags: wpf, binding, converters, foreground

it’s possible set the foreground property of a TextBlock  by TextBlock text value?
For example: Text value is Mike, foreground property is Black, value is Tim, property value is green, etc. I search with google, but I don’t find any solution.

Answer (score 7):

If you want the flexibility to do something smart, such as dynamically map texts to colors and so on, you could use a Converter class. I am assuming the text is set to bind to something, you could bind to the same something in Foreground but through a custom converter:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Foo}" 
           Foreground="{Binding Path=Foo, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}" />
```

Your converter would be defined something like this:

```
public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string text = (string)value;
        switch (text)
        {
            case "Mike":
                return Colors.Red;
            case "John":
                return Colors.Blue;
            default:
                return Colors.Black;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Obviously, instead of the simple switch statement you could have smarter logic to handle new values and such.

Comment: Want to add: If you are not using static resources, the returned value in converter should be: `new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)` to bind the field value correctly.

Answer (score 3):

you have a model view (implementing INotifyPropertyChanged) that has the Text as a property and the foreground color as a property, have the textblock bind those two properties to the model view.  the color property can depend on the text property.

Comment: I think you'll find that using this approach is much more flexible and testable than the trigger/converter approach.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the number of voted comments, I am revising the answer from @danut-enachioiu to implement the solution using `Brushes`, instead of `Colors` so that the value returned will match the type of the WPF Element Property.

```
TextBlock.Foreground is 'System.Windows.Media.Brushes'
```

Here is the revised code...

```
public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string text = (string)value;
        switch (text)
        {
            case "Mike":
                return Brushes.Red;
            case "John":
                return Brushes.Blue;
            default:
                return Brushes.Black;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```